# Defining MainButton.onClick() for Telegram Webapp correcly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to define `window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.onClick()` functionality to use the most recent values.

Lets see through code:

```
// selectedRegions is an array of strings
const [selectedRegions, setSelectedRegions] = React.useState([""]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    window.Telegram?.WebApp.MainButton.onClick(() => {
        //   window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData(selectedRegions);
        alert("main button clicked");
    });
}, [selectedRegions]);
```

Now as I update the `selectedRegions`, this `useEffect` is called for the number of times the state changes which also updates the `MainButton.onClick()` functionality. Then at the end, when the `MainButton` is pressed, in this case, `alert()` is shown the number of times the state was updated, eg, if the `selectedRegions` contain 3 values, the alert will be shown 3 times.

What I want is to somehow define this `onClick()` once or the functionality executed only once, so that I can send the `selectedRegions` only once with the most recent values back to the bot.

UPDATE 1: After looking into the function `onEvent()` in [telegram-web-app.js](https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js) file,

```
function onEvent(eventType, callback) {
    if (eventHandlers[eventType] === undefined) {
      eventHandlers[eventType] = [];
    }
    var index = eventHandlers[eventType].indexOf(callback);
    if (index === -1) {
      eventHandlers[eventType].push(callback);
    }
  };
```

It seems to my understanding that if the callback is present in `eventHandlers["webView:mainButtonClicked"]`, then it will not do anything, otherwise just push it into the array.
What I fail to understand is that somehow the callbacks are different, that's why they get appended to the array, justifying the multiple calls to it.

However, I am trying to use `MainButton.offClick()` to remove the from `eventHandlers` array, have not succeeded yet. If anyone has done so, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced exactly same issue. I had some buttons that updates state and on main button click I wanted to send that state, but as you mentioned telegram stores all callbacks in array and when you call sendData function, web app gets closed and only first callback is executed. If you tried to remove function with offClick, I think that didn't worked, because callbacks are compared by reference, but function in component was recreated by react when component is re-rendered, so, that's why offClick failed to remove that function. In this case solution would be like this

```
  const sendDataToTelegram = () => {
    window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData(selectedRegions);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', sendDataToTelegram)
    return () => {
      window.Telegram.WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', sendDataToTelegram)
    }
  }, [sendDataToTelegram])
```

If you are not familiar with this syntax - return in useEffect is callback that is called before new useEffect is called again

Or you can solve this also with useCallback hook to recreate function only when selected region state is changed. Like this:

```
  const sendDataToTelegram = useCallback(() => {
    window.Telegram.WebApp.sendData(selectedRegions);
  }, [selectedRegions])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.Telegram.WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', sendDataToTelegram)
    return () => {
      window.Telegram.WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', sendDataToTelegram)
    }
  }, [sendDataToTelegram])
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular with typescript and I ran into this problem too. But I finally found a solution: for some reason if I pass a callback like this -
"`offClick(() => this.myFunc())`" the inner "indexOf" of the "offEvent" cannot find this callback and returns "-1".
So I ended up with:

```
setOnClick() {
  let f = () => this.myFunc;
  window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.onClick(f);
}

setOffClick() {
  let f = () => this.myFunc;
  window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.offClick(f);
}

myFunc() {
  console.log('helloworld');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isShow) {
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.setText('');
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.show();
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.enable();
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.onClick(setSelectedRegionsHandler);
    }
    return () => {
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.hide();
      Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.offClick(setSelectedRegionsHandler);
    };
  }, [isShow, setSelectedRegionsHandler]);
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation of your code on why it works.

Comment: There is nothing new, @aleksandrs-vaguscenko provides same approach: using `return` in `useEffect` to call `MainButton.offClick()`. Before posting your answer, please make sure that your answer is not a duplicate of answers already given.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - to copy telegram-web-app.js to your repository and rewrite function onEvent for WebView.

I rewrote it to this:

```
  function onEvent(eventType, callback) {
    eventHandlers[eventType] = [callback];
  };
```